# How to handle event of selecting an item in <select> in html with jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, html

```
<select id ="facetFilterList" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" size="18" multiple="multiple">
```

So I want to trigger some event whenever the user clicks on an item and getting it's value as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#facetFilterList').change(function () { alert($(this).val()); })
```

The PHP part is not important here , we are working on the client side here.

Answer (score 0):

basically u can use [jquery $.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) or [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to post the value from the listbox when the user click on and and update something else back.

if you will be more specific with what you're trying to do, i bet other SO-ers will be able to help you better.

[but for starters, you can play with this.](http://jsfiddle.net/melaos/NZNZ2/)